# Use External JavaScript file to change display on div

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am currently doing this:

```
<div id="textChange" style="display:none;">Blah blah</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var d = new Date();
var funnyDate = (d.getFullYear() + "" + (d.getMonth()+11) + "" + (d.getDate()+10));
if((funnyDate>=20131916) && (funnyDate<=20131923))
{
document.getElementById("textChange").style.display ="block";
}
</script>
```

and would like to move the script to an external JS file. How do I do that? I doesn't seem to be working for me.

Thanks.

Comment: What is not working exactly? Errors would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Include this script after your `#textChange` div and it will work. For example before closing `</body>` tag:

```
...
<script src="funny-script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

This is the simplest method. You could also run this code on `DOMContentLoaded` or `window.onload` events, but looking at what your script doing I don't think it makes sence.

Answer (score 1):

**1-open notepad or notepad ++ or whatever you use as a text editor.**

**2-copy the javascript code to the text editor without  and  tags**

```
var d = new Date();
 var funnyDate = (d.getFullYear() + "" + (d.getMonth()+11) + "" + (d.getDate()+10));
  if((funnyDate>=20131916) && (funnyDate<=20131923))
{
document.getElementById("textChange").style.display ="block";
  }
```

**3-save the files with any name you want and don't forget to add the .js extension to the file for example save the file as "test.js"**

**4-copy the "test.js" to the same directory as html page.**

**5-add this line to the html page**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create a function and include this in a js file

```
function style_changer(){

var d = new Date();
var funnyDate = (d.getFullYear() + "" + (d.getMonth()+11) + "" + (d.getDate()+10));
if((funnyDate>=20131916) && (funnyDate<=20131923))
  {
    document.getElementById("textChange").style.display ="block";
  }
}
```

Now in your html give reference to the js file containing this function for example

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourscriptfilename.js" />
```

you can include this in your  section and should work

Answer (score 0):

Save the a file called `script.js` with the contents.

```
var d = new Date();
var funnyDate = (d.getFullYear() + "" + (d.getMonth()+11) + "" + (d.getDate()+10));
if((funnyDate>=20131916) && (funnyDate<=20131923))
{
    document.getElementById("textChange").style.display ="block";
}
```

And place this tag inside your HTML document. Place it just before the `</body>` so you'll know that the element `textChange` will exist in the DOM before your script is loaded and executed.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" />
```

*Make sure that `script.js` is in the same directory as your HTML document.*

Answer (score 0):

put this below code in a function

step1:

```
function onLoadCall()
var d = new Date();
var funnyDate = (d.getFullYear() + "" + (d.getMonth()+11) + "" + (d.getDate()+10));
if((funnyDate>=20131916) && (funnyDate<=20131923))
{
document.getElementById("textChange").style.display ="block";
}
}
```

Step2:-

call that function on page load

```
<body onload='onLoadCall()'>
...
</body>
```

step3:-
now move the script to another file it will work

Answer (score 0):

Put script in a separate file and name it yourScript.js and finally include it in your file

add the code within the script file

```
function changeFunnyDate(){
    var d = new Date();
     var funnyDate = (d.getFullYear() + "" + (d.getMonth()+11) + "" + (d.getDate()+10));
      if((funnyDate>=20131916) && (funnyDate<=20131923))
    {
    document.getElementById("textChange").style.display ="block";
      }
}
```

Finally add the script in your file & call the method

```
<script src="yourScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take everything between your script tags and put it in another file. You should save this file with a `.js` file extension. Let's pretend you save it as `textChange.js`.

Now the simplest thing to do would be to include the script file just after your `<div>` tag -- so basically where the `<script>` tags and code were before, write:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="textChange.js"></script>
```

This assumes that 'textChange.js' is in the same folder as your HTML file.

...

However, that would far too easy! It is generally best practice to place `<script>` tags in the `<head>` of your HTML file. You can move the line above up into the head but then the script will load before your `<div>` does--it will try to do what it does and it will fail because it can't find the div. So you need to put something around the code in your script file so that it only executes when the document is ready.

The simplest way to do this (and there may be better ways) is write the following...

```
window.onload = function () {
    var d = new Date();
    var funnyDate = (d.getFullYear() + "" + (d.getMonth()+11) + "" + (d.getDate()+10));
    if ((funnyDate>=20131916) && (funnyDate<=20131923))
        {
            document.getElementById("textChange").style.display ="block";
        }
}
```

This will mean your script is in the head where it should be and that it only performs when your whole page is ready, including the div that you want to act on.

Hope this helps.